# How can I decompress an OGG sound file using FMOD?

Tags: c++, audio, compression, fmod

Is there a way to decompress sound files using the FMOD library in c++?

I'm developing a sound editor, using the FMOD Engine library, but I got to the problem with compressed audio files, specifically OGG types.

For now I'm just reading the raw data using `FMOD::Sound::readData()`, and then normalize it and display it to the screen using SFML. This works fine with WAV files, because they are not compressed, but I need to do more steps for compressed formats.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
  FMOD_RESULT r;

  FMOD::System* m_fmodSystem = nullptr;
  int m_maxChannels = 64;
  
  // Create fmod system
  r = FMOD::System_Create(&m_fmodSystem);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  
  // Initialize system
  r = m_fmodSystem->init(m_maxChannels, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, nullptr);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  
  // Create sound
  FMOD::Sound* soundResource = nullptr;
  FMOD::Channel* channel = nullptr;
  r = m_fmodSystem->createSound("640709__chobesha__laser-gun-sound.ogg",
                                FMOD_DEFAULT | FMOD_OPENONLY,
                                nullptr,
                                &soundResource);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  


  // Get sound length in raw bytes
  unsigned int audioLength = 0;
  FMOD_TIMEUNIT timeUnit = FMOD_TIMEUNIT_RAWBYTES;
  r = soundResource->getLength(&audioLength, timeUnit);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  
  // Read sound data
  char* audioBuffer = new char[audioLength];
  unsigned int readData = 0;
  r = soundResource->readData(reinterpret_cast<void*>(audioBuffer),
                              audioLength,
                              &readData);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);



  signed short* interpretedData = reinterpret_cast<signed short*>(audioBuffer);

  // Analize data to normalize it
  signed short maxValue = -32767;
  signed short minValue = 32767;
  int interpretedDataSize = readData / sizeof(signed short);
  for (int i = 0; i < interpretedDataSize; ++i) {
    if (interpretedData[i] > maxValue) {
      maxValue = interpretedData[i];
    }
    if (interpretedData[i] < minValue) {
      minValue = interpretedData[i];
    }
  }
  
  float maxValF = static_cast<float>(maxValue);
  float minValF = static_cast<float>(minValue);
  float* normalizedArray = new float[interpretedDataSize];
  
  // Normalize data
  float maxAbsValF = abs(maxValF);
  maxAbsValF = maxAbsValF > abs(minValF) ? maxAbsValF : abs(minValF);
  for (int i = 0; i < interpretedDataSize; ++i) {
    normalizedArray[i] = interpretedData[i] / maxAbsValF;
  }
```

I read on other posts and on the FMOD documentation that I can use the flag `FMOD_CREATESAMPLE` to tell the `createSound` function to decompress the data at loadtime, instead of playtime, but It doesn't work in my current structure of the code, I'm guessing because the `FMOD_OPENONLY` prevents it from closing, and therefor it doesn't gets the chance to decompress, or something. That's what I got from the documentation.

The problem with not using the `FMOD_OPENONLY` flag, is that I cannot read the data using the `readData` function, or it returns an error flag.

Searching, I found that I can use the `lock` function, to help it decompress and to get the pointer to the data of the sound, but even with all of this, it stills appears to be compressed. I don´t know if I'm missing something.

This is the version 2 of the code, with this modifications:

```
  // Create sound
  FMOD::Sound* soundResource = nullptr;
  FMOD::Channel* channel = nullptr;
  r = m_fmodSystem->createSound("640709__chobesha__laser-gun-sound.ogg",
                                FMOD_DEFAULT | FMOD_CREATESAMPLE,
                                nullptr,
                                &soundResource);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  


  // Get sound length in raw bytes
  unsigned int audioLength = 0;
  FMOD_TIMEUNIT timeUnit = FMOD_TIMEUNIT_RAWBYTES;
  r = soundResource->getLength(&audioLength, timeUnit);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  
  // Read sound data
  char* audioBuffer = new char[audioLength];
  void* ptr2 = nullptr;
  unsigned int len1, len2;
  r = soundResource->lock(0, audioLength, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&audioBuffer), &ptr2, &len1, &len2);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
  r = soundResource->unlock(reinterpret_cast<void*>(audioBuffer), ptr2, len1, len2);
  FMOD_ERROR_CHECK(r);
```

[This is the graph I get for a WAV sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ohHH.png)

The left side is the sound loaded in the Audacity app, and the right side is my graph.

[This is the graph for the first try with the OGG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxTIf.png)

[And this is the graph for the OGG file with the modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG3hZ.png)

For what I can see, the first is the same as the second, so I'm assuming both are compressed and what I changed did nothing.

Someone knows a better way to decompress and read the raw data of a sound, preferably using this library of FMOD. If it's not possible with FMOD, what is the best way to decompress any sound file, knowing its format.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a couple minority-position takes and a sketchy description of a process I once used. Maybe the thoughts are worth consideration.

One thought: a person who is editing sound (your target audience?) has the know-how to decompress files (e.g., using Audacity), so perhaps adding this capability (handling all possible incoming audio formats) is a lower priority?

Another thought: there are likely many libraries for decompressing sound available. You could employ one of them prior to presenting the results to FMOD. I just did a search on github for "ogg c++" and was shown 51 repositories.

In my own experience, for an application I wrote about seven years ago, I tweaked some code from a Vorbis decoder source so that it output PCM rather than outputting as a .wav. With OGG, the .wav data is converted to PCM prior to compression. So, it decompresses back to PCM before converting that to a .wav. I found the point in the code where the conversion happens and edited that out, leaving the data in a decompressed PCM form.

My application was built to accept PCM, so I actually ended up saving an intermediate step.

Comment: Yeah, I could delegate the work of decompressing the audios to the user, but my goal is to make a tool like Audacity or Adobe Audition, but specialized in videogame adaptive music, so It'll be better if I could do it for the user. And, it do need to be decompressed, because I need to be able to manipulate the raw data, and then send it by parts to the audio device.
Maybe I should look for an other library, like you said, to decompress the audios, I was just hoping that FMOD could do all the work.

Thanks for the answer.